# Add Authenticated Site.com Pages to Community Tabs

Tags: community

How add a site.com Page to community + tab salesforce (like a tab)?
My community is : https://democommunity26-developer-edition.eu0.force.com/webre/

My page Name is : paginaForTabs

I compose this link : https://democommunity26-developer-edition.eu0.force.com/webre/s/paginaForTabs

But don't work
How I can Fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_communities_tab.htm&language=en_US) from Salesforce explaining "Add Authenticated Site.com Pages to Community Tabs". Hope this helps.

Extracts from the link.

In this case, you need to create a Web tab that points to your Site.com page.

1. In the Properties pane for your page, select Show Salesforce Header.
   Selecting this option ensures that you see tabs in your community.
2. Enter the tab name as it should appear on the tab in your community.
   The web tab you create must have the same name.
3. [Determine the correct URL for the page.](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_communities_url.htm&language=en_US) The URL must be in the
   following format
   https://mydomain.force.com/mycommunity/s/, where pagename
   matches the name of your page.
4. From Setup, enter Tabs in the Quick Find box, then select Tabs.
5. In Web Tabs, click New and enter the name of the tab as it appears
   in the Tab Name field in your page properties.
6. On the Step 3 screen, paste the URL you created in the Button or
   Link URL text box
7. Return to the Create Community wizard and add the new tab to your
   community.

To preview the private page in your community, you must publish your Site.com site.

Comment: how te remove the second salesforce style page? http://s10.postimg.org/ft6dehdfd/problema.jpg